# Encode chinese and russian characters

Tags: r, windows, character-encoding

A have a file which contains chinese and russian characters:

```
> df <- data.frame(names = c("Алексей"    ,"Валерий",    "Ефим" ,      "立显荣朝士", "文方运际祥"))
```

When I look at the data frame it looks like it it not beeing encoded:

[image]

But when I fefer to the column directly it seems to be correctly encoded:

```
> names$X.U.FEFF..name.
[1] "Алексей"    "Валерий"    "Ефим"       "立显荣朝士" "文方运际祥"
```

And then when I try to export the data with:

```
> write.table(names, "path_to_file/names.csv", row.names = FALSE, sep = ";", col.names = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF8")
```

I get the same mess which looks like:

[image]

Can someone give me an advise how to export the data such a way that it is correctly encoded?

P.S.: As this hat to run on an older version of R ( R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- Good Sport) and many packages are not available for that version a base R solution would be great.

Comment: your file link is dead.

Comment: @amatsuo_net done :-)

Comment: The broken display would be OS dependent. Windows does not have good support for UTF-8 and many things are messed up when dealing with non-ascii characters. 
You might be able to solve this issue by changing the system locale to an appropriate language and change system locale of R. http://koheiw.net/?p=490

Comment: Can confirm that encoding works fine on RStudio running linux. The link provided by @amatsuo_net should solve your issue.